# bash: How avoid expanding variables etc?

Tags: bash

Sorry about the somewhat vague subject. What I am after is a way to `ssh` to a server while copying my preferred profile to the server. The general idea is to do something like `ssh -t [server] "cat a_profile > .bashrc;bash -li"`, where I have expanded `a_profile` as a here-document:

```
function ssh
{
  h=$1
  /usr/bin/ssh -t $h "cat >.bashrc <<!
unalias -a
alias ll='ls -lpN'
set -o vi
export LESS=X
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]
then
  export PS1="\"'\\h # '\""
else
  export PS1="\"'\\h $ '\""
fi
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=AKEY
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=ASECRETKEY

function ssh
{
  h="'\$1'"
  /usr/bin/scp ~/.bashrc "'\$h'":.bashrc
  /usr/bin/scp ~/.vimrc "'\$h'":.vimrc
  /usr/bin/ssh -A "'\$h'"
}

function ,
{
  sudo bash --init-file /home/jan/.bashrc
}
!
bash -li
"
}
```

It seems to work, except that the `if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]` part is evaluated when I call the `ssh` function, so the test reads `if 1000 -eq 0 ]`. And any way, I think I need to work on the quotes, they can't be healthy, nested like that. Any thoughts about how to get this to work?

Comment: Any reason why you don't just `scp` the file to the remote host?

Comment: well, yes, I want to do this every time I connect to a remote server. I have a lot of servers, none of which share a filesystem, so it would be convenient. Also, it is an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want id -u evaluated by the receiving host.  You'll want to ensure it arrives intact.

`"\"id -u\""`

This should give your local bash a set of quotes to swallow without letting it gobble the command.